# I can not install python 3.6.5 in windows 7 64 bit version. What should I do?

Tags: python

If I run the python 3.6.5.exe file, this error shows up.

[image]

When I installed python 3.2.5 using msi installer, it installed fine.
Then I uninstalled it and downloaded python 3.6.5 web based installer and started using run as an administrator. A pop up came up and it was showing initializing but no activity for a while. So I cancelled it. There's a python 32 folder in my C drive and I can't delete it because it said permission denied. Now if I run the web based installer as administrator, it doesn't show the pop up anymore. What should I do to install python in my computer?

Comment: Try restarting your computer and run the installer again.

Comment: I did. And the python 32 folder went away. But run as administrator didn't bring the pop up back again. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Did you still get the error in the screenshot again or did nothing happen?  This seems to be a very unusual problem.

Comment: I am thinking maybe somehow the installer broke when you cancelled it

Comment: I have 4 installers. None seem to work. I have tried a lot of windows update too. No results.